# Sort checked row

Tags: apex, lightning, custom-field, sort

I have a tab where i save my values in first column. And when I check checkbox I want to copy value from first column then sort it and save in second column. How to implement sort? Any suggestions

**Update**
Apex:

```
 }

  try {
      sortApRec.sf__c = sortApRec.uns__c; 
      sortRec.add(sortApRec);

    if ( sortRec.size() >1  ) {  
         sortRec.sort(); 

         update sortRec;  
        sortRec.clear(); 
        //sortRec.sort();
    }  
         if ( sortRec.size() > 0 ) { 
       // sortRec.sort();     
        update sortRec;  
        sortRec.clear();    
    }  

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! This question is not quite up to the expected quality. I would recommend adding in more information on your use case, as well as anything you have already tried and relevant code examples. See here for more info: [salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Please read more about [ask], then [edit] your question to include any relevant code or additional information so we can better assist you.

Comment: Thank you guys, the stuck is that I can't pass the value from Unsorted to the Sorted column and sort it.

Comment: I found the reason, now the value is perfectly saved in the Sorted column, but I still can`t sort the result. I updated the post. Any help will be appreciated